# KDNET received an out of sequence ping packet

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I am using WinDbg 10.0.10586.567 over NET. Both the host and target are running Windows 10 10586, and are in the same subnet.

I have been debugging successfully for some time. But suddenly, I get the following errors when I try to connect to the target system:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Using NET for debugging
Opened WinSock 2.0
Waiting to reconnect...
Connected to target 10.0.0.102 on port 50000 on local IP 10.0.0.100.
KDNET received an out of sequence ping packet.
The target machine restarted without notifying the debugger.
Forcing a debugger reconnect...
Shutdown occurred at (Fri May  6 08:34:33.724 2016 (UTC - 7:00))...unloading all symbol tables.

Packet failed authentication.  Please make sure the host and target encryption keys match exactly. Also make sure you don't have multiple target machines pointed at the same network port n your host.
Bad packet sent from 10.0.0.102.
Run nslookup 10.0.0.102 from a command prompt to get the machine name.
```

Yes, the key that I enter is what I configured the target for. There is only one target that is being debugged. Somehow, packets are getting dropped by WinDbg on the host.

I believe this is a problem with my debugging host, but have never run into this kind of problem before.

Has anybody seen this before, and know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution cannot be provided for these scenarios, but few suggestions are here that could be possibly helpful

1. Increase the virtual memory page size on your HOST system.
   Custom page size Min 1.5 times to Max 4 times of the Physical RAM installed.
2. Enable symbols caching on the HOST system. cache*c:\symbols;

HOST system : The system on which **windbg** is running